# How to deploy Unity's Test Runner's "Build All Test" .apk to multiple devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, command-line, adb, test-runner

I am trying to automate the testing portion of my game, by using Unity's Test Runner. I have Unity building and deploying to a single device via command line, but I don't see if there is an option to target multiple devices.

Is there a way to specify it as part of the Unity command line prompt?

At least I have the path for the generated .apk file. I found the path for the .apk at

```
~\{ProjectPath}\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\build\outputs\apk\debug\launcher-debug.apk
```

I suppose I can use this and distribute with adb, instead of Unity.